# Can a HTML element's current appearance be temporarily frozen?

Tags: javascript, css, html, dom

The background is that I have an extremely complex web application that has various modal editors. I display a short animation when opening one of those editors. But, BEFORE I even initialize the editor and start the animation, I need to DEINITIALIZE the "main" user interface because it uses lots of resources. So, I would like to make a frozen "screenshot" (it needs to be fast, so html2canvas is a no-go) of the main user interface, then remove it from the DOM, then initialize the modal editor and start the animation.

Does DOM have an API for this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no, you cannot.  The best you can do is convert your HTML to an SVG and copy the resulting image to a canvas.

If you really have so many DOM elements that you have to prune the tree before showing your dialog, I'd rethink your application and whether or not this all belongs on a single page.

Comment: Thanks, the problem is that this is a packaged app inside a WKWebView for iOS, but yeah, it could probably be split into several WKWebViews. I've been using a native iOS API so far for capturing a portion of the rendered HTML, which actually works very well, but that API got significantly slower in iOS 12 and is now close to unusable.